# Spring boot self injection for @async @Transactionalwith simple constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, transactions

I have class:

```
public class MyService {
  private final ObjectService objectService;

  public MyService(ObjectService objectService) {
    this.objectService = objectService;
  }

  public void calculate() {
 update()
  }
@Async
@Transactional
  public void update() {
    objectService.update();
  }
}
```

but @async not work. The best way work around? what about using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)

Comment: Self-invocation — calling the async method from within the same class — won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`@Async` wont work in self invocation, but you can make self injection to solve this:

```java
public class MyService {

  private final MyService self;
  private final ObjectService objectService;

  public MyService(ObjectService objectService, @Lazy MyService myService) {
    this.self = myService;
    this.objectService = objectService;
  }

  public void calculate() {
    self.update()
  }
  
  @Async
  @Transactional
  public void update() {
    objectService.update();
  }
}
```

Here we are adding a proxy to service through the reference named `self`, then just call `self.update()` instead of `update()` and everything will be just fine.

Don't forget to annotate the constructor variable with `@Lazy` to avoid getting into circular reference